# Fastest way to get average stock in a period over several static stock values

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a table that keeps track of static stock values per product per day. Only when the stock is changed, a new record is added to the table. So there is not a record for every product on every date.

So in short, there are 3 columns that matter:

1. ProductId
2. Date
3. Stock

It's getting rather slow to determine the average stock, for like 100.000 products. We tried several solutions with some CTE's, but I was wondering if there are other smart ways that I don't know yet to determine an average stock for this.

Example of data for one product:

`id                date             stock
  5          2012/01/07                 3
  5          2013/04/04                 2 
  5          2013/05/15                 1 
  5          2013/08/07                 12 
  5          2014/06/02                 11`

Now i'm running statistics over a period from 01/01/2013 until 31/12/2013. What would be the fastest way to determine the average stock over that period?

I'm really hoping for some smart thing that I don't know yet.. ;-)

Comment: can you show your query/cte and execution plan

Comment: Have you tried to use a calendar table to generate the full year, expand the stock and use a simple `AVG` over this projection?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JOIN` to join your query with itself, where the row in the right is the next update following the row in the left:

```
id    date          stock   prev_date     prev_stock
5     2012/01/07    3    
5     2013/04/04    2       2012/01/07    3
5     2013/05/15    1       2013/04/04    2
5     2013/08/07    12      2013/05/15    1
5     2014/06/02    11      2013/08/07    12
```

Now you could calculate the time difference for each row, from which you could calculate the weighted average.